# form in php not redirecting to page after submitting

Tags: php, html, angularjs, forms

i have a form in php which i created like a calculator, i have used angular js to display the user entered value on the display, which i designed like below:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['entering'])) {
    header("Location: https://www.google.com");
    exit();
} else {
    $msg="Something Went Wrong. Please try again.";
}
?>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class='ct-inner'>

      <!-- Project HTML Below -->
      <div ng-app="" class='calculator'>
        <div class='inner'>

          <div class='innerIn'>
            <div style="height:49px;" class='screen active'>
              <div class='output'> {{name}}</div>

              <div class='screen-layer'></div>
            </div>


            <form method="post" action="">
              <div class='controls'>


                <div style="margin-top:5%;" class="form__group">
                  <input ng-model="name" type="password" class="form__input" id="name" placeholder="Password" required="" maxlength="6" />

                </div>
                <div style="margin-left:35%; margin-top:1%;" class='control-pad operator-pad1'>

                  <input type="button" class='button med oper' name="entering" value="ENTER">
                </div>

              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- Inner in End -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is my whole code, when i am trying to submit the form entering values its not going to different page after submission, can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: It is easier to understand what you are doing if you can just post the logics (i.e. the php code) without all the css.

Comment: Your form does not even have a submit button. If you have any additional JS here to make this form submit anything in the first place, then you need to show us that.

Comment: @MortenSickel i understand, but i think there is some problem in my css which is making the form not submit, thats why posted whole code

Comment: I am pretty sure POST never happens, as there is no submit button or any submit form logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Docs:

> Since the role of forms in client-side AngularJS applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload that sends the data to the server. Instead some javascript logic should be triggered to handle the form submission in an application-specific way.
>
> For this reason, AngularJS prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the `<form>` element has an action attribute specified.
>
> You can use one of the following two ways to specify what javascript method should be called when a form is submitted:
>
> - [ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive on the form element
> - [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive on the first button or input field of type submit (input[type=submit])

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<form>` Directive API Reference - Submitting a form and preventing the default action](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action)

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not submitting because you don't have a submit button in it, you have to add button with **type="submit"** if you want to submit the form

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

If you want to submit the form to another php script, don't forget to set the form **action attribute**

Edit:

Add my button and var_dump the content of $_POST variable on the top of the page, it is probably empty after submit.

Comment: this is not my issue, i had given the button not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="submit"` instead.

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['entering'])) {
    header("Location: https://www.google.com");
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    <head><title>the title</title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="entering" value="Go to google.com">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: changed, still not submiting

Comment: wrap the input in a form tag

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the  your code this seems to work now is redirected to Google.com.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['password'])) {

    header("Location: https://www.google.com");
    exit();
} else {
    $msg="Something Went Wrong. Please try again.";
}
?>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class='ct-inner'>

      <!-- Project HTML Below -->
      <div ng-app="" class='calculator'>
        <div class='inner'>

          <div class='innerIn'>
            <div style="height:49px;" class='screen active'>
              <div class='output'> {{name}}</div>

              <div class='screen-layer'></div>
            </div>


            <form action="" method="post">
              <div class='controls'>


                <div style="margin-top:5%;" class="form__group">
                  <input ng-model="name" type="password" class="form__input" id="password" name = "password" placeholder="Password" required="" maxlength="6" />

                </div>
                <div style="margin-left:35%; margin-top:1%;" class='control-pad operator-pad1'>

                  <input type="submit" class='button med oper' name="entering" value="ENTER">
                </div>

              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- Inner in End -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```